# Order Total Due even after successful payment; PayPal Standard Method

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-standard

I am using the default Magento PayPal Standard payment method (Magento 1.9.3.6). Everything is correct except that it shows a Total Due even after successful payment. The invoice is created and marked "Paid", but in the Information tab, the "Total Paid" is zero and "Total Due" equals the order grand total. This also causes the order to stay in processing state, even after shipping the order. What's the reason and how should I fix it?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.